# Getting Justified Text in UITextField

Tags: cocoa-touch

How do I get justified text with UTTextField. It does have an textAlignment property.  But the UITextAlignment constant only has left, right, and center justification.

What I am seeking is the Justified text common in word processing app with text flush with both left and right edges. This is a read only text field.

I have seen it in few iPhone apps.  So it seems I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an overkill maybe, but one way seems to be to use a WebView for it and style the text with CSS.

Comment: I don't think a web view is suitable for any reason besides truly web–related content.

Comment: It's quite versatile actually. There's at least one high profile app using web views for styled content; Quora. And it's known for it's snappiness.

Answer (score 1):

UILabel and UITextField do not support full-justified text.  If you want it for a UITextField, you would have to create a subclass of UITextField and override `drawTextInRect:`, splitting the text into words and using `sizeWithFont:` to figure out how to space them along each line.

I cannot imagine what would be worth the trouble.