# is there any way to do JUSTIFY the text in a UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, text-justify

Is there any way to 'justify' the text in a `UITextView` in an iOS app?

Comment: Not out-of-the-box. See duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402339/getting-justified-text-in-uitextfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not possible in a UITextView. There are two ways to achieve this.

1. Write a method that adusts the text with spaces in a way that it fits the textview exactely
2. Use CATextLayer. That class has a property to set the alignment to Justifiy.

I hope this helps you out.

Sandro Meier

Comment: Like the possible use of CATextLayer - I'll try this myself! +1

Comment: Thanks. I did it myself. But if the layer has not a big width, the result looks ugly...

Comment: I followed this approach and did it view `UILabel` and `drawRect:` http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/